# Huygens' Principle Integral Dimensionality

Tags: huygens-principle

Huygens' principle, when describing plane waves, and its subsequent corrected versions, are based on integration of radial waves (usually with some factors multiplying them inside the integral) over a wavefront. This is generally presented in the context of the wave in a space containing an opaque screen containing a narrow open aperture.

Assume the space is the two-dimensional (2D) $x$-$y$ plane, with a plane wave propagating along the $y$-axis. Also, assume a linear opaque screen, with a narrow aperture, is parallel to the $x$ axis.Then the above integral is over the wavefront at the screen, and is an integral over $x$.

I would like to consider Huygens' principle for the same plane wave in the same space, but without an opaque screen, or any other object (a “free space” case). Of course, we can think of there being a wavefront for each value $y$. Therefore, if we wish to decompose the plane wave into radial waves, should there also be integration of the radial waves, not just over a single wavefront, but also integration over all wavefronts, so that there is a double integral of radial waves, over both $x$ and $y$?

I have been researching Huygens' principal, and it’s subsequent versions, but have not seen this free space case addressed. The implication is that the 2D plane wave, in free space, would be decomposed into a radial wave originating at every point in the 2D space, not just over every point along a single wavefront line, since the choice of that single wavefront would be arbitrary.

Comment: A follow-up question is, even if integrating over x and y is valid for some kind of radial wave decomposition, what is the value of such a decomposition in terms of physical application or insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate over both $x$ and $y$ you need to take phases into account, otherwise you should get 0 because of destructive interference of circular waves originating half a wavelength away from each other in $y$-direction. If you do that, I assume you should be able to correctly calculate the oscillation of some arbitrary point in the plane, but you do not gain any information, because that oscillation is already given by the plane wave itself, so I do not see why anybody would want to do that.

Another problem is, that when representing the waves by complex exponential functions, if I'm not mistaken, the integral with the phases for the oszillation at the origin would look something like
$$
\int dx \int dy ~ \exp \left (i \left(k \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + \underbrace{y}_{\text{phase}}\right) \right) -\omega t\right)~,
$$
which seems to be hard to solve.